# Does React.js handle "static" differently? compound components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

Shouldn't the static keyword refer to a global variable for the class itself and is not related in anyway to the instance of the component?

then why in the compound component pattern, when we instantiate multiple components of the same class they tend to behave seperatly ,although they depend on a static variable

So to my understanding to the "static" keyword is that it's a global variable to all instances of the class and a change in that variable should change all the components in that class

```js
  static On = (props)=> props.on ? props.children : null 
  static Off = (props)=> !props.on ? props.children : null 
  static Button = ({on,toggle})=> <Switch on={on} onClick={toggle}/>
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child=>{
      return React.cloneElement(child,{
        on:this.state.on,
        toggle:this.toggle
      })
    })

  <>
    <Toggle onToggle={onToggle}>
      <Toggle.On>The button is on</Toggle.On>
      <Toggle.Off>The button is off</Toggle.Off>
      <Toggle.Button />
    </Toggle>


    <Toggle onToggle={onToggle}>
      <Toggle.On>The button is on</Toggle.On>
      <Toggle.Button />
      <Toggle.Off>The button is off</Toggle.Off>
    </Toggle> 
  </>
```

I honestly expected both components to be toggled on and off when i affected one of them, could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subcomponents themselves are static, and not bound to any single instance of the Toggle component. However, the *props* you're passing into the static subcomponents are based on `this.state`, which *is* bound to each instance.

If you make `state` static as well (or just give `Toggle` a `static on` property), changing that property with a Button click will cause both `Toggle`s to change.

Note that this is different from `this.state`, so `this.setState` won't work, and changing `Toggle.state.on` won't trigger a re-render. You need to call `this.setState` in the parent, in order to trigger a re-render for both Toggles.

```js
class Toggle extends Component {
  static state = { on: true }

  toggle = () => {
    Toggle.state.on = !Toggle.state.on

    // reRenderParent should make a `setState` call in the
    // parent in order to re-render both Toggles.
    this.props.reRenderParent();
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-snowflake-whiu7

Answer (score -1):

This is what is happening:

`On`, `Off` and `Button` are tree components that happen to be attached to the class `Toggle`. In this case think about the relation as a namespace. The only think this is allowing you to do is to use the three components this way: `Toggle.Component`. It would be the exact same thing if you just declare the three components in their own files, import them and use them without the `Toggle.` namespace.

Every time you render them React is cloning the component and rendering a new one. That is what this code is doing:

```
return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child=>{
      return React.cloneElement(child,{
        on:this.state.on,
        toggle:this.toggle
      })
    })
```

So, when you toggle one the others don't toggle because they are different.